# Can I access and create the reminders in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

These are the ones I'm talking about: [Google Reminders](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2015/12/add-to-dos-to-your-google-calendar.html)

Or alternatively can I see my reminders from the [Google Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/get_started) in my Google Calendar?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?  I'm curious, too.

Comment: You can't unfortunately. At least a month ago or so.